# how to prevent the iceServers address from leaking

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I need to use the turn service in my webrtc project,but it accidentally shows in client (on the page chrome://webrtc-internals/)
[image]
i wonder know How to prevent the iceServers address from leaking, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the motivation here? TURN servers are supposed to be publicly known to establish P2P connections...